# How to remove synced iPhone data in iTunes 11?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

I didn't have a free outlet to plug my iPhone charger into, so I plugged it into the USB port of my work computer (Macbook Pro) to charge.  Anyway, iTunes 11 and iPhoto opened up!  I forgot that iPhones automatically sync with iTunes (as I never sync with anything -- I don't back anything up -- my contacts and calendar are synced to Google, and that's all I really care about on my phone).  I was able to disable iPhoto from opening, but I can't do that with iTunes.  I did click on the Preference to "Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically" but this was after I think some syncing took place.  How can remove whatever data was synced?  I think it was just the apps that got synced, but how can I be sure?  Is there some folder hidden somewhere in the system that I can check?  And if it is only the apps, how do I remove that information?

This is my work computer, and I don't want any information from my personal phone to end up on it.

I learned my lesson -- don't plug anything personal into a work computer.

Comment: Remove the pictures from your iPhone, put them on your homePC or dropbox or whatever and sync again.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy way to have iTunes show you the last sync data.

You could use Time Machine to compare the files in ~/Music/iTunes after the sync with before it. (Or just restore that entire folder or the entire Mac from a backup before the sync.)

The automatic sync that happens with a new computer is not any actual transfer of files as you would have to go into iTunes and set up the rules or accept the automatic sync of content so unless you already had synced that device to that iTunes library before no data would transfer.